# How to validate parent-child relationships in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Category` model which can have multiple parent and child categories. I have modelled this using a `Hierarchy` model which contains `parent_category` and `child_category` attributes.

I can validate that the rows are unique using

`validates_uniqueness_of :parent_category_id, scope: :child_category_id`

This (and the corresponding unique index in database) takes care that there are not multiple rows representing the same parent-child relationship.

But, I want to prevent someone assigning parent of a child as it's child. For ex. if Category A is a parent of Category B, assigning Category A as a child of Category B should result in a validation error.

The only approach I can think of is querying the database in a `validate` method.

```
def child_parent_messup
  unless Hierarchy.where(child_category_id: parent_category_id, parent_category_id: child_category_id).blank?
      errors[:base] << "This child is also a parent of the same class." 
  end
end
```

How can this be improved?

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is a 'cyclic' relationship - and, IMHO, there is no default validator built into rails for this.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simpler, you can do the following:

- Add a collection with has_many relation say, parents, which returns its parent as well its parent's parent
- Check whether the children_id is included in the above parents collection

Your design seems little complicated, see whether you can make it simpler. May be SIngle Table Inheritance makes sense here, including for better validation handling. I might be wrong as I don't have much idea about the requirement.

Comment: Using a `has_many` call seems to be equally expensive. I do not understand how Single Table Inheritance will work. There is a singe `Category` model.

Comment: has_many might be more easy to understand as its more readable.  Regarding STI, I was thinking whether it make sense to have 3 different models i.e.  1. Category without any parents or children 2. Category with parents 3.Category with both parents and children